# Override ui-autocomplete-loading css class in primefaces 4.0

Tags: jquery, ajax, primefaces, jquery-autocomplete

I am using `p:autocomplete` along with `p:ajaxStatus`. I am also using `p:dialog` as a default behaviour of `p:ajaxStatus` which blocks the ui when ajax request is being sent.

Now my question is: **How to override this default behaviour for only the autocomplete component**? I don't want to block the page when the user types something. I have also tried to override `ui-autocomplete-loading` class in my css page but failed.

```
`.ui-autocomplete-loading { background: #fff url('img/loading.gif') no-repeat right center; }`
```

Note: I am using primefaces 4.0. I doubt whether `ui-autocomplete-loading` class is removed or not in this version.

Answer (score 0):

Set the 'global' attribute to false to prevent your autocomplete from triggerring the ajaxStatus.

`<p:autoComplete ... global="false"/>`

No need to change any CSS.

Comment: Already tried this, but p:autocomplete doesn't seem to have any global option. I can see it in p:commandButton.

Comment: I think you mean <p:ajax global="false"/>